# How can I get the value of the x property in a Alignment(x,y) class in Flutter?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, properties

I'm new to Flutter and Dart. I used the [example project](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/physics-simulation) found on the Flutter Docs to build my app.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/physics.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: PhysicsCardDragDemo()));
}

class PhysicsCardDragDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: DraggableCard(
        child: FlutterLogo(
          size: 128,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// A draggable card that moves back to [Alignment.center] when it's
/// released.
class DraggableCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  DraggableCard({this.child});

  @override
  _DraggableCardState createState() => _DraggableCardState();
}

class _DraggableCardState extends State<DraggableCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  /// The alignment of the card as it is dragged or being animated.
  ///
  /// While the card is being dragged, this value is set to the values computed
  /// in the GestureDetector onPanUpdate callback. If the animation is running,
  /// this value is set to the value of the [_animation].
  Alignment _dragAlignment = Alignment.center;

  Animation<Alignment> _animation;

  /// Calculates and runs a [SpringSimulation].
  void _runAnimation(Offset pixelsPerSecond, Size size) {
    _animation = _controller.drive(
      AlignmentTween(
        begin: _dragAlignment,
        end: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
    // Calculate the velocity relative to the unit interval, [0,1],
    // used by the animation controller.
    final unitsPerSecondX = pixelsPerSecond.dx / size.width;
    final unitsPerSecondY = pixelsPerSecond.dy / size.height;
    final unitsPerSecond = Offset(unitsPerSecondX, unitsPerSecondY);
    final unitVelocity = unitsPerSecond.distance;

    const spring = SpringDescription(
      mass: 30,
      stiffness: 1,
      damping: 1,
    );

    final simulation = SpringSimulation(spring, 0, 1, -unitVelocity);

    _controller.animateWith(simulation);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _dragAlignment = _animation.value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: (details) {
        _controller.stop();
      },
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        setState(() {
          _dragAlignment += Alignment(
            details.delta.dx / (size.width / 2),
            details.delta.dy / (size.height / 2),
          );
        });
      },
      onPanEnd: (details) {
        _runAnimation(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond, size);
      },
      child: Align(
        alignment: _dragAlignment,
        child: Card(
          child: widget.child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to animate other properties of the DraggableCard() besides its position; specifically I want to dynamically change its rotation and opacity based on the horizontal drag.

In order to do that, I'm trying to get the value of _dragAlignment so I can  feed it to a Transform.rotate(), but the value corresponds to a coordinate and I only need to read the value of the x coordinate.

So in other words I need to extract the X value from the class Alignment(x, y) which corresponds to the _dragAlignment. I have tried many things but nothing worked.

I searched here and other places for solutions but couldn't find any help, maybe I'm not asking the right questions.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question and if it's been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this,

```
var align = Alignment(1,2);
var xCoord = align.x;
var yCoord = align.y;
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Where should I declear it?
If I declear it where -dragAlignment is decleard, it throws this error: error: The instance member '_dragAlignment' can't be accessed in an initializer. (implicit_this_reference_in_initializer at [spring_physics] lib/main.dart:186)

Comment: I think you can access it like this, `_dragAlignment.x`

Comment: I decleard it like this
var xCoord = _dragAlignment.x;

But it throws the error I posted in the previous comment. If, instead, I declear it in the Gesture Detector(), the Dart Analysys in Android Studio doesn't throw any error but when I run it in debug an error is displayd on the device:
The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toDouble()

Comment: Thanks! :) I fixed it by giving _dragAlignment.x directly to the Transform.rotate(angle: _dragAlignment.x)!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shri Hari for your help :)

I solved my problem by declaring

```
var xCoord = 0.0;
```

Where _dragAlignment is also declared and than using

```
child: Transform.rotate(

                angle: -_dragAlignment.x/200
```

Directly in the GestureDetector().

I also had to edit the values in onPanUpdate because it looked like it wasn't dragging anymore but you just need to increase the details.delta.dx...

Like This:

```
return GestureDetector(

  onPanDown: (details) {
    _controller.stop();
  },
  onPanUpdate: (details) {

    //print(_dragAlignment);
    setState(() {

      _dragAlignment += Alignment(

        details.delta.dx / (size.width / 300), // X drag sensitivity
        details.delta.dy / (size.height / 9), //Y drag sensitivity

      );
    });
  },
  onPanEnd: (details) {
    _runAnimation(details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond, size);
  },
  child: Align(
    alignment: _dragAlignment,
        child: Transform.rotate(

            angle: -_dragAlignment.x/200,
              child: Card(
                child: widget.child,
              ),
        )
  ),
);
```